# Informatica dynamic filename generation issue

Tags: informatica

I am trying to create a dynamic target filename. I want the same filename as source file. I am using the help of currentlyprocessedfilename in source structure and filename option in target structure. But my target filename is not generated as it is supposed to. the name of the target file is not same as source filename.I hope there is no session setting required here.please help

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where and how are you setting the value for your target file name. You should use a port in some expression to set a value for it and connecting the port to the `FileName` port in your `Target Transformation`.

Reffer [this walk-through](http://www.disoln.org/2012/06/dynamically-change-your-flat-file-name.html) for details.